# Angular 2 - moved to @types giving error "cannot find name 'require'"

Tags: angular, typescript

I have moved my project from old typings to types-publisher. Most of my dependencies are resolved except I keep getting this error **Cannot find name 'require'**
here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./src/custom-typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "types": [
    "core-js",
    "jasmine",
    "node",
    "lodash",
    "jquery",
    "requirejs",
    "angular",
    "googlemaps"
  ]
}
```

in my package.json for "devdependencies", I have these

```
"@types/angular": "^1.5.16",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.25.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.28",
```

I installed @types/requirejs too... but this error won't go away. 
Is there something I am missing or adding incorrectly?

I am using webpack 2.1.0.beta.25 for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `tsconfig.json` as follows as `typeRoots` and `types` are `compilerOptions` properties as per [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [
      "core-js",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "lodash",
      "jquery",
      "requirejs",
      "angular",
      "googlemaps"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/custom-typings.d.ts"
    ]
  }
}
```

Also check [documentation for types, typeroots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) which says that `If typesRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included` so check by removing `typesRoots` or making change in `typesRoots` property settings.

Comment: Thanks, it resolved the issue. don't need requirejs anymore.